# Is there a readily available classification of holomorphic embeddings of the Riemann sphere into projective three space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I would like to have a formula for the most general embedding of the Riemann sphere into projective three space, in coordinates. The Veronese maps would be an example of such an embedding, but I'm looking for the most general formula.

I have read the section in Miranda's book "Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces" describing holomorphic embeddings of Riemann surfaces into projective space, where he discusses the concept of very ample line bundle, and how linear systems of a divisor are related to these maps.  I have also read the following paper, which mentions a characterization of these maps

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226072647_The_topology_of_spaces_of_rational_functions

However, the result is mentioned in passing, and I am not sure if it answers the same question (he uses "base point preserving" maps, which may not be the same).

I can probably derive this myself using the techniques in Miranda's book, but I'm wondering if there is a paper/book that does this already, so I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I do not think any such general formula exists. Any such embedding in 3-space of degree say $d$ are given by taking the Veronese embedding in $d$-space and then projecting from a general linear subspace of dimension $d-4$. The key word here is general and then it is difficult to write explicit formulas. In other words, you can take 4 general homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ in 2 variables and then the associated map turns out to be an embedding.

Comment: Thank you, that is a useful characterization of the maps.  It is still a little bit abstract for me, even though I could understand it with some practice.  Do you know of a good reference where they would go through this construction in detail.  Miranda's book gives a good introduction, but if there is a reference that has some more explicit details that would be great.

Comment: When you write this construction, do you mean facts about projections? This can be found in most books (dealing with secant varieties), for example, Shafarevich.

Comment: Ok, great I will take a look at that book.  I am mostly interested in maps of degree 1, maybe that will simplify things.  Thanks!

Comment: So in that case it seems I can just take four linear polynomials and that is the most general embedding of degree 1?  That seems to agree with the construction in the paper by Segal, so maybe it is rather simple.

Comment: (I mean homogeneous degree one polynomials)

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking bout. There are essentially only two linearly independent linear polynomials on the Riemann Sphere.

Comment: According to your first answer, you said you can take 4 general homogeneous polynomials of degree d in 2 variables and the map is an embedding.  So for degree 1 that would just give four linear homogeneous polynomials.  I understand that only two are linearly independent, but is it necessary for the four polynomials to be linearly independent?  If so, how do you write the maps of degree 1?

Comment: If you take 4 general linear polynomials, this si the same as 2 and the rest zero and you will end up with a line in 3-space. Not very exciting, methinks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50861/discussion-between-teddy-baker-and-mohan).

Comment: Are you allowing linear coordinate transformations on the target space, in which case you can choose coordinates such that two of the polynomials vanish?  Otherwise I don't see how you can choose two of them to be zero.  I would like to have a fixed coordinate system, so maybe I'd need all four polynomials.